# Browser doesnt' run on netbens when I try to open a Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, browser, netbeans

I compiled a servlet with jsk19 with netbeans. Servlet is deployed on ApacheTomcat10. I can open that Servlet writing directly servlet URL pattern in my browser, but on Netbeans if I run this servlet a message appears "browser cannot be run". I have checked many times my configuration with "TOOLS" "OPTION" "GENERAL". I also tried to start browser (Firefox) via "shell" to be sure netbeans path configuration of browser was right and it was right. I Also tried to configure my browser clicking with right click mouse on my project and set up browser configuration inside option, but same trouble came-up.  My log file error in netbeans reports nothing about this error. Any guess?

Comment: Update your question with the following information: [1] When you navigate to **Tools > Options > General**, what are the selected values for _Web Browser_ and _Proxy Settings_? [2] What happens when you click the **Test Connection** button for those selections?  Does it work or fail? (A screen shot would help.) [3] State your version of NetBeans.

Comment: Test connection works every time fine. Selected value browser is "default-system-browser" linked to [/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr], it runs fine if invoked by shell. Netbeans version is 19.

Comment: What do you mean by the _"browser configuration inside option"_? Not true solutions, but a couple of possible short-term workarounds: [1] Right-click your project to open **Properties**, then navigate to **Run** in the **Categories** list, and explicitly select Firefox as your browser from the **Browser** drop list. (Presumably your current selection there is _"IDE's default browser"_?) [2] Alternatively, use **Run > Set Project Browser**. But neither of those approaches will resolve the underlying problem that your `<Default System Browser>`  configuration seems to be invalid...

Comment: ...To resolve that, navigate to **Tools > Options > General > Web  Browser**, select `<Default System Browser>`, click **Edit...**, and make a note of the value in the **Process** field. Then repeat with `Firefox` as your **Web Browser** selection. Are the values in the two **Process** fields identical? If not, update the **Process** value for `<Default System Browser>` to that of your `Firefox` setting.

Comment: "browser configuration inside option" means Tool>Option>General>Web Browser>Edit. Follow this steps in netbeans you open a Window where you can configure or edit a new or old Browser to use in Netbeans. In that section mentioned above in Process Field there is the path to "browser start command". In my case it points-out to /usr/lib/fire-fox/firefox; I tried to to launch firefox-esr following the path I write before and it runs correctly. Clicking on Project name Properties>Run you get a drop list of browser to choose. In this second case browser doesn't start as before.

Comment: I don't know how to update my question posted here. I have written new one so I guess to delete thi question because malformed and useless. I hope my new one be improved.